# segue when clicking on collection view cell embedded in table view cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview, uicollectionviewcell

I have the following app logic

TableView Controller => Table View Cell => CollectionView embeded in each table view cell

I want when I click on a collection view cell to segue the table view controller to another controller.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Here's my code:

In tableViewControler

```
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "book", for: indexPath) as! BookTableViewCell
            let books = (indexPath.row == 2) ? trendingbooks : newbooks
            if (cell.collectionView === nil) {
                cell.addCollectionView();
            }
```

```
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "bookDetail", sender: indexPath)
```

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
        let dc = segue.destination as! DetailViewController
        dc.data = self.tableRowData;
    }
```

In BookTableViewCell

```
    func addCollectionView () {
        let flowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        flowLayout.scrollDirection = .horizontal

        let cellWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 3
        let cellHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 3
        flowLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: self.frame.height)

        //You can also provide estimated Height and Width
        flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: self.frame.height)

        //For Setting the Spacing between cells
        flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 20
        flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 20

        let cellReuseIdentifier = "collectionCell"
        self.collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect(x: 0,
                                                             y: 0,
                                                             width: self.frame.width,
                                                             height: self.frame.height),
                                               collectionViewLayout: flowLayout)
        self.collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        self.collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.collectionView.backgroundColor = .clear
        self.collectionView.delegate = self
        self.collectionView.dataSource = self
        self.collectionView.register(BookCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier)

        self.addSubview(collectionView)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the function you are looking for is `tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("bookDetail", sender: indexPath)
}
```

Comment: When the user clicks on a collection view cell in tableview cell how do I get them to segue all the way to the table view controller?

Comment: If I'm understanding your question correctly, you need to make sure that the destination is set correctly. As someone pointed out in another answer, you should make sure you are casting the destination view controller correctly e.g.: ```let destination = segue.destination as? DetailViewController```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use segue like this way in your case:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == segueIdentifier,
       let destination = segue.destination as? DetailViewController,
       let selectedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow,
       let selectedCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? YourCell 
    {
        let collectionView = selectedCell.collectionView
        // Then do your stuff here
    }
}
```

Comment: When I click on the collection view cell in the table view cell inside the table view, the didSelectRowAt tableViewController function does not get triggered, so I can't call performSegueIdentifier

Comment: You might need a callback from your collection view cell selection which contains information of the tableview cell that the collection view is embedded in. And then perform your segue.

Answer (score 0):

The embedded collection view's delegate (the BookTableViewCell) will be the first to hear about the selection.  The question is how should that tableview cell convey the selection to the VC that contains it. One answer is to define a delegate on the BookTableViewCell that passes info about the selection from the embedded collection view to the containing VC.

So when configuring the `BookTableViewCell`, set its delegate to the VC that contains it and have the VC implement this method to perform the segue.

```
protocol BookTableViewCell Delegate {
    func didSelectInEmbeddedCollection(cell: BookTableViewCell, at: IndexPath)
}
```

Have the cell's implementation of the embedded collection view's `didSelectItem` method, call this `didSelectInEmbeddedCollection`.

Comment: Where do I put didSelectInEmbeddedCollection?

Comment: Define the protocol and a delegate property on the custom BookTableViewCell.  When configuring the cell (after dequeue) set the delegate to self (the containing vc).  The containing vc then must implement didSelectInEmbeddedCollection.  It can trigger the segue from there

Comment: The key idea is that the collection view is two levels down from the VC, so you sort of need two levels of delegation.  The first level is provided by the collection view itself.  The second must be provided by the custom cell.  Complex, but its a complex arrangement of views that you're starting with

Comment: I get an error when I try to set a delegate on the tableviewcell, do you happen to know why @danh?

Comment: I'd have to see the code and the error.  You'll get one if the VC doesn't declare itself as conforming to the protocol defined by the cell

Comment: It calls the delegate function, but is not calling the prepare function before it errors out. Should I be putting the prepare function outside the vc?

Comment: Inside the vc is right. But you don’t explicitly call prepare for segue. You call performSegue, and the prepare method gets triggered.